# Algorithm performance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance, profiling, benchmarking

I am testing an algorithm for different parameters on a computer.
I notice the performance fluctuates for each parameters.

Say I run for the first time I got 20 ms, second times I got 5ms, third times I got 4ms: 
But the algorithm should work the same for these 3 times.

I am using `stopwatch` from C# library to count the time, is there a better way to measure the performance without subjecting to those fluctuations?

Comment: Time a thousand (or ten thousand) runs of the same code. You'll get more stable results.

Comment: Well, the first time might be running various tasks such as static initializers, loading data into memory, JIT compiling, etc. Is it consistently slow for the first time or just randomly slow? Also, those are pretty small data sets that can be subject to just typical system CPU usage by other processes, thread handling, etc.; what happens if you run it for longer and for many more iterations than just 3?

Comment: It sounds like this algorithm may use disk I/O.  Why?  Because the second and third trials look like some code accessed cached data compared to the first which got data off an external disk. The suggestions about profiling will help the most.

Comment: This is one of the difficulties of using benchmarking to guide a real decision about which code you use. While the fluctuations are probably due to the memory hierarchy getting filled(a "hot cache"), or maybe some runtime optimization in the virtual machine, you need to consider that these factors may or may not always be present in a live production environment. If one algo speeds up more significantly than the other after being run multiple times, it is more dependent on the cache hierarchy for performance - and this is very valuable info.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the world of benchmarking.

With code that finishes in 4ms, you aren't going to be able to get an accurate measurement running it just once. Page faults, static initializers, JIT, CPU cache, branch predictors, and context switches all affect run time, and at that small of a test any one of them could easily create a huge variance. Run it in a loop until the stopwatch measures over 1 or 2 seconds, then divide by the amount of times it ran.

Also, you should run the code once or twice *before* you start the `Stopwatch` to ensure the code is JITed and hot in the CPU's cache.

Here's code I use when I want a poor-mans benchmark instead of profiling. It does a bit more than what I described above -- such as removing overhead of Stopwatch from the benchmark, and drilling down until it's confident it's found the smallest execution time.

runCount = the amount of times it should check for the next smallest execution time.

subRunCount = if the Action you pass in already runs a loop, or runs over multiple items etc. and you want to measure the amount of time spent per item, put the count here.

```
static double Benchmark(string name, int runCount, int subRunCount, Action action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: warming up...", name);

    // warm up.
    action();

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: finding ballpark speed...", name);

    // find an average amount of calls it fill up two seconds.

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        ++count;
        action();
    }
    while (sw.ElapsedTicks < (Stopwatch.Frequency * 2));

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: ballpark speed is {1} runs/sec", name, MulMulDiv(count, subRunCount, Stopwatch.Frequency, sw.ElapsedTicks));

    // The benchmark will run the Action in a loop 'count' times.

    count = Math.Max(count / 2, 1);

    // Start the benchmark.

    Console.Write("{0}: benchmarking", name);
    Console.Out.Flush();

    long minticks = long.MaxValue;
    int runs = 0;

    while (runs < runCount)
    {
        sw.Restart();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            action();
        }

        sw.Stop();

        long ticks = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        if (ticks < minticks)
        {
            // Found a new smallest execution time. Reset.

            minticks = ticks;
            runs = 0;

            Console.Write('+');
            Console.Out.Flush();
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            ++runs;
            Console.Write('.');
            Console.Out.Flush();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: speed is {1} runs/sec", name, MulMulDiv(count, subRunCount, Stopwatch.Frequency, minticks));

    return (double)count * subRunCount * Stopwatch.Frequency / minticks;
}

static long MulMulDiv(long count, long subRunCount, long freq, long ticks)
{
    return (long)((BigInteger)count * subRunCount * freq / ticks);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First run takes more time, because at execution time a **just-in-time (JIT) compiler translates the MSIL into native code** (see [Managed Execution Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k5532s8a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

To eliminate the *first-run problem* you can either use:

- [**Ngen.exe (Native Image Generator)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6t9t5wcf.aspx);

> The Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe) is a tool that improves the performance of managed applications. Ngen.exe creates native images, which are files containing **compiled processor-specific machine code**, and installs them into the **native image cache** on the local computer. The runtime can use native images from the cache instead of using the just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile the original assembly.

- or run **multiple iterations** with skipping the result for the first run (but you need to make sure that it went through all the branches to have them compiled).

To profile the code **without including `StopWatch`** in it, you can use the [**instrumentation profiling**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182369.aspx) from the [Performance Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) included in Visual Studio.

> The [**instrumentation profiling**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182369.aspx) method of the Visual Studio records **detailed timing information** for the function calls, lines, and instructions in the profiled application:

[image: Elapsed Time]

You can also analyse "*hot paths*" and compare reports from multiple different runs.

[image: Hot Path]